# Zoomed in camera in Zoom meetings?

Tags: zoom, zoom-meeting

Can I make my camera to get zoomed in in Zoom meetings? My camera is placed farther away than I want it to be since I connect my laptop to a television and captures a lot of my room, which I don't want to show. Is there any way I can make it zoom into the portion I want to show?

I can't seem to find an answer on Google since Google treats the operation *Zoom in* and the company Zoom as the same.

Comment: Please add more details. Apparently you are using the built-in camera of your laptop, if so please add more details like the operative system name and version the brand of your laptop as some vendors might include software to control the web cam.